# PHP max_input_vars security expectations

Tags: web-application, php, attack-prevention, configuration, attack-vector

Considering a site that handles large `POST` data, would it be unreasonable and dangerous to set the `php.ini` `max_input_vars` to something like 100000?

I know this is a vector for DOS attacks, but don't other configurations such as `post_max_size` help to prevent that? Are there any ways to safeguard against hash collisions while still having `max_input_vars` set at a high value?

Other considerations would be the effect on `GET` and cookies. Can someone please explain the consequences of this configuration and the exploits involved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vulnerability is about hash collisions and not necessary about the size of the request.

So yes setting the directive to a higher value is probably not a smart idea (even when you are limiting the `post_max_size` or any of the other related directives).

Also if you need to set it to something like 100000 you should really reconsider what you are doing in most cases.